# Write "true"/"false" to an INI file based on task selection in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, ini

In the `[Tasks]` section I have:

```
[Tasks]
Name: "userexpericeneimprovement"; \
    Description: "{cm:JoinUserExpericeneImprovement}"; \
    GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0;
```

and in `[INI]` is this specific command:

```
[INI]
FileName: "{app}\ceip.ini"; Section: "General"; Key: "enabled"; \
    String: "{code:GetUserJoin}";
```

My aim is to check the selected task and then the `[Code]` `{code:GetUserJoin}` part will do the filling in the `ceip.ini` file as `"true"` or `"false"` whichever is checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial enough to be implemented even without any Pascal Script with use of [`Tasks` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams):

```
[INI]
FileName: "{app}\ceip.ini"; Section: "General"; Key: "enabled"; String: "true"; \
    Tasks: userexpericeneimprovement
FileName: "{app}\ceip.ini"; Section: "General"; Key: "enabled"; String: "false"; \
    Tasks: not userexpericeneimprovement
```

---

If you want to use the Pascal Script, the implementation is also trivial with use of [`WizardIsTaskSelected` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardistaskselected):

```
[INI]
FileName: "{app}\ceip.ini"; Section: "General"; Key: "enabled"; \
    String: "{code:GetUserJoin}";
```

```pascal
[Code]
function GetUserJoin(Param: string): string;
begin
  if WizardIsTaskSelected('userexpericeneimprovement') then Result := 'true'
    else Result := 'false';
end;
```

Comment: thank you very much! i have run this code successfully...  you are so enthusiastic and kind!...